# How to move data from table to an other in Mysql big table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, bigdata, database

i have a big table about 200,000,000 row MYISAM with a composed primary key
but i have no index.

and i would like to create an index but the probleme is that the table server is broken when i execute the add index request :

```
ALTER TABLE `db`.`table` 
ADD INDEX `index_0001` (`col1` ASC);
```

So i will create a new table and configure needed index and move data to the new table and rename it.

i tried this manip :

```
INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (field1,field2,..) select field1,field2,....from eventdata limit 100000 offset 0 ;
INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (field1,field2,..) select field1,field2,....from eventdata limit 100000 offset 100000 ;
INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (field1,field2,..) select field1,field2,....from eventdata limit 100000 offset 200000 ;
.......... etc
```

But when the offset become more then 100,000,000 the query line response become more slow.

is there any other solution ?

tahnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `limit 100000 offset 100000 ;` means MySQL searched the 100000 records and get the record from 100001;

Search the 100000 records is TABLE FULL SCAN, so it is very slow;

Use `Primary key` to search is better way, like `... where pk >=100000 and pk <= 199999`

If `Primary key` can not divided into Number, use `Join`

`select field1,field2... from tbname tb1,(select pk from tbname limit 100000 offset 100000)tb2 where tb1.pk = tb2.pk`

Use `Primary key` to search the record is better than TABLE FULL SCAN;

Comment: Thanks. 
but i have a composite primary key from 3 fields

Comment: @ALWAN This sample is only a sample, root cause is table full scan, use primary key or other unque key is better way :P